# Open encrypted sqlite3 in iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite

I have an encrypted sqlite3 with AES128 encryption

And I used the **libsqlite3.0** to fetch the data to my app ...

so how to open it ??

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The links you provided talk about encrypting storage across the whole device; However if the goal is that the user not be able to open the database file directly then will not help you, as the only thing that protects against is your data being accessed in the event the device is stolen. It also relies on the user to set it up, the app cannot mandate that the device storage is encrypted.

[sqlcipher ios-tutorial](http://sqlcipher.net/ios-tutorial/)

Comment: I don't think your reply matches the question.

Comment: yes i want make user to read something useful before post question.

Answer (score 0):

You have one of three cases:

1. The individual entries are encrypted
2. The entire file is encrypted
3. The database is encrypted with SqlCipher or another encrypting version of SQLite

If #1 you'll be able to retrieve entries but they will be gibberish.  Decrypt after retrieval.

If #2 or 3 then the DB will not open with standard SQLite.

If #2 you simply decrypt the file (using onboard encryption services) and then access "normally".

If #3 you must install SqlCipher (or whichever encrypting DB was used).